# Create a checkbox when checked it should show certain input fields & hide other input fields, within a Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" name="Seasonal" value="Seasonal" id="isASeasonal" onclick=" if ($(this).is(':checked')) { console.log('Worky'); $('#ShowIfChecked').show(); $('#HideIfChecked').hide(); } else { $('#HideIfChecked').show(); console.log("No Worky"); }" />
```

I've been attempting to do this with jQuery, but it hasn't been functioning properly, I have also done a thorough amount of research for ways to condense this code. I was trying to condense the statement with a ternary operator. If you could please assist me with a possible solution that would be great! Thanks (Ternary Solution would be amazing)

Comment: can you show the HTML ? ALSO what you have tried so for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your `onclick` to a function, because at least for me, it is easier to see whats really going on.

So change

```
 <input type="checkbox" runat="server" name="Seasonal" value="Seasonal" id="isASeasonal" 
       onclick=" if ($(this).is(':checked')) { console.log('Worky'); $('#ShowIfChecked').show(); $('#HideIfChecked').hide(); } 
       else { $('#HideIfChecked').show(); console.log("No Worky"); }" />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" 
    name="Seasonal" value="Seasonal" id="isASeasonal" onclick="myFuncton(this)" />
```

Within your view:

```
<script>
    myFunction(myCheckBox)
    {
        if(myCheckBox.Checked)
        {
           console.log('Worky'); 
           $('#ShowIfChecked').show(); 
           $('#HideIfChecked').hide(); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
           $('#HideIfChecked').show(); console.log("No Worky");
        }  
    }
</script>
```

Now to get the expression/Ternary Solution you want, you can change this script to look like this:

```
<script>
    myFunction(myCheckBox)
    {
       myCheckBox.Checked ? (console.log('Worky'), $('#ShowIfChecked').show(), 
           $('#HideIfChecked').hide()); :  ($('#HideIfChecked').show(), console.log("No Worky"));
    }
</script>
```

[You can find more Info about Ternary Solutions here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Comment: Thanks for answering every part of my question it helped me create the ternary Solution that I wanted.

Comment: @HecticHiccups No problem, Happy to help :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue with your code is that you have mis-matched quotes in the HTML due to the `console.log("X")` calls in your code that is messing up the attributes of the `input` element. If you check the console you'll most likely see some errors relating to this.

It's for this reason, amongst many others, that it's considered bad practice to use inline script (or CSS styling for that matter). The other issues are that it's bad for separation of concerns and makes the code harder to read an edit. It's *far* better practice to attach your event handlers using unobtrusive Javascript, like this:

```js
$('.seasonal-checkbox').change(function() {
  $('#ShowIfChecked').toggle(this.checked);
  $('#HideIfChecked').toggle(!this.checked);
});
```

```css
#ShowIfChecked {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" name="Seasonal" value="Seasonal" id="isASeasonal" class="seasonal-checkbox" />

<div id="ShowIfChecked">Checked!</div>
<div id="HideIfChecked">Not Checked!</div>
```

Note the use of the `change` event over `click`, so that the event is still fired for user who navigate the web using the keyboard. Also note the simplified logic using `toggle()` to hide and show the relevant content in a single call to each method which negates the need for an `if` statement - and by proxy a ternary expression too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware about having an external script file. The internal script was placed by a team mate, and it was the only way he's gotten it to work. I'm currently attempting to reorganize his code. Although the script works properly when i try to hide input fields within a "MODAL" it wouldn't hide the input fields when the checkbox was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

We dont write code like this. It fails on every code review.

Do this:

$('#isASeasonal').click(function() { ...});

https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

```
Seasonal Address:&nbsp <input type="checkbox" runat="server"  clientidmode="Static" name="Seasonal" value="Seasonal" id="isASeasonal"/>

$('#ShowIfChecked').hide(); //Hid What needs to be shown if checked.
$("#isASeasonal").click(function () { //Used Click event on checkBox
($("#isASeasonal").is(':checked')) ? (console.log('worky'), $('#ShowIfChecked').show(), $('#HideIfChecked').hide()) : (console.log('no worky'), $('#HideIfChecked').show(), $('#ShowIfChecked').hide());
```

What fixed my issue was that in ASP.net I needed to add clientidmode="static" to the div's that I was trying to hide & show. I still don't understand the reason why, I'm currently looking more into it but this is what worked for me but above you can see the majority of the final product with the ternary operator!! Yay.